# Laravel 5.1 - Show my session cart

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

to show in header menu my products of my cart session, I'm passing the session "cart" from my controller to my view, like this:

FrontController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');

        return view('index',compact('cart'));
    }
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/','FrontController@index');
```

my layout principal.blade.php ( it work well)

```
@foreach ($cart as $item)

all items of my session cart

@endforeach
```

MY QUESTION:

there is a way to pass the cart session directly to all my views?? OR I must always pass the cart Session for each view ? i have about 24 views, i must do each view like my view homepage index.php ??

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to pass session data from controller? Sessions are available everywhere. This should work without passing anything from a controller:

```
@foreach (session()->get('cart') as $item)
    all items of my session cart
@endforeach
```

Comment: Most of the times you will want to share a `Cart` instance (which may use sessions to store it's items)... but not in this case. It's just the session itself, so this is the best answer I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

use [data sharing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

add to `boot` method in your `AppServiceProvider`

```
view()->share('cart', \Session::get('cart'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect job for Laravel's [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers).

Create a new service provider, let's call it `ComposerServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Share $_cart to every view
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            view()->share('_cart', \Session::get('cart'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the service provider within `config/app.php`. You can also compose variables to specific views only by replacing the `*` wildcard.

You may noticed I've added a underscore prefix `_cart` to the variable. I do this so you know the variable is shared and not passed by the controller.

Comment: I done like you say but now i have a error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2016\resources\views\layouts\principal.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2016\resources\views\layouts\principal.blade.php)

Comment: What variable are you passing to that `foreach()`? I would need more details.

Comment: foreach ($cart as $item)

all items of my session cart

endforeach   variable like name product $item->name, category, quantity, ecc.. all values of my session "cart" maybe the foreach is wrong

Comment: Maybe you should try `foreach ($_cart as $item)` if you copy-pasted my answer. Anyway, if you're only using the session you wouldn't need a view composer.

Comment: yes i dont need, but maybe i will need provider for other issue, i will try as you say, thank you for your help!